# kotlin extension method access in another kt

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-extension

I'm thinking about adding a **global** extension method to String in just one file,and wherever i use a String i can always use this extension.

But i failed to find a way to do so...i just paste the extension everywhere now.

extension here in A.kt:

```
class A{
    ......
    fun String.add1(): String {
        return this + "1"
    }
    ......
}
```

and access like this in B.kt:

```
class B{
    fun main(){
        ......
        var a = ""
        a.add1()
        ......
    }
}
```

I've tried everyting i can add like `static` and `final` but nothing worked.

Comment: Hey, this should absolutely work. Are you using IDEA? Are there no suggestions for imports?

Comment: @zsmb13 i'm using Android Studio with kotlin plugin ver 1.1.3-2,and no import suggestions,it said Unsolved reference

Comment: Can you use classes that are declared in other files?

Comment: @zsmb13 yep,i can

Comment: Do you have an exact error message? Is it just "Unresolved reference" on the extension's name?

Comment: Is the extension function a top-level function and all your classes either in the same package as the extension function or imported?

Comment: @zsmb13 yes, well i mean i just put a extension fun in a kt file and try to access b.add1() in another kt file

Comment: @zsmb13 well not in same package and two kt files have no relationship

Comment: Can you tell us what the error that you're getting says exactly?

Comment: Well, if they are in the different package, you may have to import the extension function, but I don't sure about it.

Comment: @zsmb13 well i failed again in importing the extension [tears]

Comment: Now that you've updated the code in your post, I've figured it out, see my answer below.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Make sure your extension function is a [top level function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#function-scope), and isn't nested in a class - otherwise it will be a [member extension](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#declaring-extensions-as-members), which is only accessible inside the class that it's in:

```
package pckg1

fun String.add1(): String {
    return this + "1"
}
```

Then, if your usage of it is in a different package, you have to import it like so (this should be suggested by the IDE as well):

```
package pckg2

import pckg1.add1

fun x() {
    var a = ""
    a.add1()
}
```

Comment: I wrote the extension inside a class! This is why i failed!

Comment: same here, inside a class :)

Answer (score 13):

You can use the `with`-function to use a member extension outside the class where it was defined. Inside the lambda passed to `with`, `this` will refer to the instance of `A` you pass in. This will allow you to use extension functions defined inside `A`. Like this:

```
val a =  A()
val s = "Some string"
val result = with(a) {
    s.add1()
}
println(result) // Prints "Some string1"
```